# Android Json parsing string cannot be converted to json object error

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to send parameters such as username and password.

I got an error like String cannot be converted to jsonobject.

I dont know what this happening.Anyone pls help me my code is:

```
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            try{
            obj.put("username","test");
                obj.put("password","test");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                urlJsonObj, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }

        });
        // Adding request to request queue
      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,json_obj_req);
    }
```

Comment: on which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are creating JSONObject and putting values in it. Make sure the response received is Json, because your onResponse method accepts JSONObject. You could be receiving String value as response, which could not be converted to JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your response is actually a string and not a json object i.e. `{"object":"value"}` but rather `"object:value"`. You need to sniff your response via either Stetho, Fiddler or reenact your request via Postman (or Fiddler)

======================

This doesn't answer your question, but this will help you tremendously and make your life easier.

Highly recommend using Gson and Retrofit to make HTTP requests and parse Gson objects easily.

https://github.com/google/gson

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: i used volley for json parsing is it the problem?

Comment: Retrofit and Volley accomplish the same thing, but there are many instances where retrofit better fits your needs in terms of ease of use and in many cases, faster.

What's likely happening is the string returned isn't a JSON object

Comment: @Dawit that's a fair question, when you look at some of the most popular open source apps and most widely used open source libraries, you'll see okhttp and retrofit (paired with gson) is used the vast majority of the time (subjective interpretation again) also a recommended approach https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices#networklibs